# Creating spatial index returning an error when executing

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like some suggestions on what I am doing wrong with creating a spatial index. When I run this command, it is giving me an error.

create table Points
(
Name varchar (20) not null,
location Point not null,
description varchar (200),
Primary key (Name)
)

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX `location` ON `Points` (`location` ASC);

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to get rid of ASC.
As of MySQL 8.0.12, ASC and DESC are not permitted for SPATIAL indexes